# jquery fading sequence

Tags: jquery, html, foreach

I am attempting to fade in a set of divs, one after another. I thought I could use the simple For Each function that jquery offers. My code is as follows:

```
$('#menu_activate').click(function(){
  $('div.section').each(function(i){
    $(this).fadeToggle();     
  });
});
```

The good thing about this is that it does iterate through the divs and they all fade in when I click the activate button. The problem is that there is NO DELAY between the elements fading in.

Any ideas? I tried the timeout function to no avail...

***Also, fadeToggle is a custom jquery function that works as you would expect.***

Thanks in advance. Tom.

Comment: I take it by the timeout function you mean `setTimeout` - what didn't work about it? That is the generally accepted way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for that one... yeah I figured it was the usual way of doing this, but it needed a little more than a setTimeout function it would seem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer!

```
  var myTimeout = 0;
  var myIncrement = 300; // Wait 300ms between each div
  $('#menu_activate').click(function(){
    $('div.section').each(function(i){
      setTimeout(function() { $('#section_'+i).show(); },myTimeout);
      myTimeout += myIncrement;     
    });
  });
```

It was the increment that I wasn't thinking about when I did it... and with Adam's answer, it wasn't referring to the DIV's with "this" so I had to give them individual ID's and iterate on that instead. So close Adam. Very impressive and thankyou for being so helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the `setTimeout`, and you want the timeout to increment with each div.  The issue here is that the `fadeToggle`s are all being called right after one another, with no delay.  Therefore, you have to introduce a delay yourself.  There's a couple of ways you can do this, here's one:

```
var myTimeout = 0;
var myIncrement = 300; // Wait 300ms between each div
$('#menu_activate').click(function(){
  $('div.section').each(function(i){
    setTimeout(function() { $(this).fadeToggle() },myTimeout);
    myTimeout += myIncrement;     
  });
});
```

Basically set the `fadeToggle`s to happen after a timeout which increments with each div.

Comment: Thankyou! Very elegant. I had to tweak it a little bit to get it to work, but you sent me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu_activate').click(function(){
    $('div.section').each(function(i){
        $(this).queue(function() {
            $(this).fadeToggle();
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });
});
```